# mock uuid for unit test in angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

i have a case where i need to mock a uuid to run and pass the test cases,

```
import * as uuid from "uuid"

export class Test{

    createData() {
        for (let item of raw_data) {
            this.data_to_post.push({
                ...item,
                id:uuid()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

and my test cases are

```
describe("test this", () => {
    it("should crete data for post", async () => {
        let raw_data = [
            {
                name: "name-1",
                mobile:"******"
            },
            {
                name: "name-2",
                mobile:"******"
            },
        ]
        let data_to_push = [
            {
                name: "name-1",
                mobile: "******",
                id:"0000-0000-0001"
            },
            {
                name: "name-2",
                mobile: "******",
                id: "0000-0000-0002"
            },
        ]
        await componet.createData()
        expect(componet.data_to_post).toEqual(data_to_push)
    })
})
```

can anyone give me a answer how to mock the uuid for running this cases or any other possibility's

i've tried spying and creating class for the uuid and none of it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the ID to the `createData` function. In your tests then, you'd pass whatever fixed value you wanted.

The production code that calls `createData` would generate the UUID and pass it to that function.

Comment: hi, thankyou for your answer from it i understood that you want to pass the id to the test functions, i'm testing the `createData` function and in that i have a id generator and i want to mock the package generated value.